# A curious class in the Hochschild cohomology of graded algebras

Tags: hochschild-cohomology

If $A$ is a ($\mathbb Z$-)graded algebra, we can define its Hochschild cohomology in the usual way, via the standard complex of $A$-bimodules:

$$C_*(A)=\cdots\rightarrow A\otimes A\otimes A\rightarrow A\otimes A.$$

Since $A$ is graded, then so is the envelopìng algebra $A^{op}\otimes A$, therefore there is a ($\mathbb Z$-)graded $Hom$ in the category of $A$-bimodules, that we can use to define the Hochschild cohomology complex,

$$C^{*,\bullet}(A)=Hom_{A^{op}\otimes A}^{\bullet}(C_*,A).$$

Therefore Hochschild cohomology is bigraded $HH^{*,\bullet}(A)$ (I'm just interested in $A$ as a bimodule of coefficients).

Following some computations of mine, the $(1,0)$-cochain $\delta$ which multiplies each homogenoeus element in $A$ by its degree

$$\delta(x)=|x|\cdot x$$

seems to be a cocycle, and its cohomology class

$$\{\delta\}\in HH^{1,0}(A)$$

is surprisingly (in my opinion) non-trivial since it can somehow detect the degree of any other cohomology class $y\in HH^{p,q}(A)$, $|y|=q$, via the Lie bracket
$$[\{\delta\},y]=|y|\cdot y.$$
That formula actually holds at the cochain level. It's turned out to play an important role in a current project and I wonder whether anybody has seen this class, or anything like that before. Is there maybe any mistake in what I say?

Notice that it is a very particular phenomenon of the graded setting. In the ungraded case $\delta$ is trivial already as a cochain.

**EDIT:** The degree of $y$ is $q$, not $p$ (which is what was written before).

Comment: Avramov and Herzog in "Jacobian criteria ..." use the Euler morphism (in the commutative setting) $\delta \in Hom(\Omega_A,A) = HH¹(A)$ in a way that reminds me your question (compare e.g. their lemma 1.15 with your formula). Sorry if too unrelated to your question.

Comment: Thanks @Vinteuil ! I'm happy to see that this cochain has appeared before. I'm trying to understand their lemma 1.15. I haven't been able so far to relate it to the formula with the Lie bracket. Actually, that lemma looks like a way of trivializing $\delta$. First time I considered $\delta$ I thought it should be trivial in cohomology, since it is defined for *any* algebra. But the formula with the bracket says it's not, and I've been unable to find any mistake...

Comment: Your cocycle is in fact an homogeneous derivation of the algebra (tangent to the obvious action of the multiplicative group), the so called Eulerian derivation. It shows up in many contexts, usually more or less implicitly. For example, you can see it in Goodwillie's theorem on cyclic homology of graded algebras.

Comment: Notice that sometimes the class of $\delta$ in cohomology is zero. For example, if $A$ is the Weyl algebra $\mathbb C\langle x,y|xy-yx=1\rangle$, graded with $x$ in degree $1$ and $y$ in degree $-1$, then the Eulerian derivation coincides with $[xy,\mathord-]$, so its class in $HH^1$ vanishes. The class of $\delta$ cannot be zero if the algebra is, say, has component of degree zero contained in the center, of course. (I don't understand you last sentence: how do you define $\delta$ for an ungraded algebra?)

Comment: Thanks, Mariano, it's good that the cocycle is known, and even has a name! In your previous example, the since you're working over a characteristic 0 field, my Lie bracket formula would say tha Hochschild cohomology vanishes in positive degrees, and this is true for the Weyl algebra, isn't it? BTW, I don't know that theorem of Goodwillie, which paper of him should I look at?

Comment: When I say positive degree, I mean internal degree (given by the grading of $A$) as opposed to Hochschild degree.

Comment: This cochain appears in a beautiful symplectic geometry paper of Abouzaid and Smith. See theorem 2.6 of  http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.5535v1.pdf.

Comment: I should say that the upshot of theorem 2.6 is a characterization of formality for an $A_{\infty}$ algebra via this cochain.

Comment: @FernandoMuro, see section 4.1 in Loday's *Cyclic Homology*. He only talks about the action of your $\delta$ on homology because his book is about homology (!) but you can do most of the same things with cohomology. OTOH: indeed, as soon as the eulerian derivation is inner (and you have $\mathbb Q$ in your field) you know that the internally homogeneous componenents of non-zero degree of homology vanish(in my example, the algebra is $\mathbb Z$-graded and we get vanishing of positive and negative components)This argument is used all over the place in concrete calculations with of graded things

Comment: If the field os f psitive characteristic, you only get that the componenenst of degree which are not divisible by the characteristic are zero; you can use this to cut down muchly the computation of cohomology of the Weyl algebra in positive characterstic (I don't know a reference for this, but it is surely known to experts)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez puedes poner tus comentarios como respuesta para que pueda aceptarla?